# To what extent do virtual particles exist, according to the models behind them?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, virtual-particles

I've seen countless questions where people asked whether virtual particles exist or to what extent they exist, and all seem to have been answered with the following: virtual particles are just a very useful mathematical tool for making predictions. So I'm asking a different question. **Let's assume for the sake of discussion that the models describing virtual particles, such as quantum field theory and perturbation theory, are "correct" instead of useful mathematical tools for making predictions.** In that case, what do they say about the extent to which virtual particles exist?

By this I mean the following: they don't seem to have clear individuality - you wouldn't be able to count them even if you could detect them - yet they have very real effects, such as mediating forces. So do they exist as separate, hypothetically countable things, or are they just a collective smear of perturbance?

Also, I'm not interested in discussing the semantics of the word "particle."

Edit: People don't seem to be getting what I'm asking, so I'll rephrase. QFT is a bunch of mathematical models, but let's assume that it's also "right." It's analogous to assuming that imaginary numbers are real. With this assumption, what does it say about virtual particles and whether they exist as their own things? How much do virtual particles act like real particles?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129304/discussion-on-question-by-zucculent-to-what-extent-do-virtual-particles-exist-a).

Answer (score 5):

My (far from expert) opinion is that virtual particles are a colorful language to describe QFT interactions and really shouldn't be taken too seriously. Virtual particles refer to internal lines in a Feynman diagram, so they really are a calculational tool at best and not fundamental entities in the theory (unlike real particles).

Further, it should always be recalled that each Feynman diagram is but one in an infinite Dyson series that is supposed to represent the actual evolution (in the interaction picture with free particles entering and exiting) -- so we shouldn't really imagine e.g. the electromagnetic interaction as particles shooting virtual photons at each other, as that's just the first order term in an infinite expansion (and even then it doesn't represent spacetime trajectories or anything concrete like that). These matters are complicated further by the likely fact that summing the whole series (in QED) diverges!

Personally, I take any talk of virtual particles as substitute for "complicated QFT interactions which we don't quite understand but may calculate perturbatively gives..."

Answer (score 2):

> QFT is a bunch of mathematical models, but let's assume that it's also "right. It's analogous to assuming that imaginary numbers are real. With this assumption, what does it say about virtual particles and whether they exist as their own things?

If you are talking about mathematics, of course all functions used in a consistent mathematical model exist as "their own thing", by construction.

*Real particles* are defined in particle physics as elementary particles that are described by a [four-vector](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) whose length is a real number, as defined in mathematics.

[image: invarmass]

> The length of this 4-vector is the rest energy of the particle. The invariance is associated with the fact that the rest mass is the same in any inertial frame of reference

The invariant mass of the virtual particles in your assumption, is not the real number assigned to the  particle or , in case of complex systems the length of the four vector describing the exchange . Only incoming and outgoing particles have a fixed real number invariant mass (the one that defines a given particle) . The virtual particles have an invariant mass dependent on the limits of integration of the Feynman diagrams of the particular problem.

Why are they labeled with the particular particle name? Because they carry the necessary quantum numbers that identify [elementary particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle) in addition to their mass,(lepton, baryon, charge, color ..) of the particular interaction so that quantum numbers are conserved at the Feynman vertices. Virtual particles are mnemonic place holders to satisfy  conservation laws for the particular interaction under study.

> How much do virtual particles act like real particles?

In terms of conservation of quantum number flow  they are the same as real particles.